# DynamoDB Secondary Index on Multi-Value Type

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table that has a hash key of type Number and an attribute that is a multi-value set of numbers.

Assume the hash key is a `group_id` and the multi-value set is a set of members of that group (`user_id`s)

I want to be able to query `Which groups is user X in?`

I know I can easily do this by de-normalizing the data and also storing a table of `user_id`s to sets of `group_id`.

Before I do that, I want to be sure that there is no way to put a Secondary Global Index on to the multi-value attribute so that I can use one table and still get decent performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only create a GSI for a scalar-type attribute. The [scalar type attributes are](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes) `Number`, `String`, `Binary`, `Boolean`, and `Null`.

From the [*Managing Global Secondary Indexes* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.Creating):

> Each index key attribute must be a scalar data type, not a multi-value
>   set. You can project attributes of any data type into a global
>   secondary index; this includes scalar data types and multi-valued
>   sets. For a complete list of data types, see [DynamoDB Data Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.Creating).

Answer (score 1):

Given a base table schema of HashKey=group_id and RangeKey=user_id, you can add a GSI to with the reverse schema. The HashKey of the GSI would be user_id and the RangeKey would be group_id. This GSI will answer the question: "Which groups is user X in?". You do not need to create a second table and maintain it. In fact, DynamoDB will automatically propagate changes from your base table to a GSI, so you do not have to worry about keeping the index up to date.

Comment: But will that work for multi-valued fields? I don't want to keep individual records for each user in a group. I want to have one record per group, with the multi-value field contain all of the users. That way a query for "who is in this group?" only requires one read operation. If I store each group -> user pair, I may be looking at thousands of reads just to get the membership of a group.

Comment: While this GSI might use multiple items to represent your data, you do not need to do GetItem calls equal to the number of group,user pairs. Instead, you can do a range [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on the group and get up to 1MB worth of items, and paginate through thousands of pairs in just a few Queries. Finally, the Query API reads sequentially, so you only consume capacity as if all the items Query read were one item. So if Query returns 100 256-byte items, you will not incur 100 RCU, you will incur 25kb/(4kb/RCU) = 7 RCU.

Comment: That is very insightful. While Mike answered my question in the strict sense, you have pointed out a better way to solve my underlying problem.